# How to get price from second table if data exists else from first table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables
2)- First Table where I store all product details like name, price, weight, etc.
1)- Second Table where I store updated price with product_id

I want to fetch an updated price with product_id from the second table but if the product_id is not available on the second table then the price will come from first table.

Comment: Please add sample data and table structure for both tables.

Comment: Look like case..when and a left join can solve the problem

Comment: let sql =
        `SELECT count(*) as allProducts from catalogs` +
        condition +        
        `;select catalogs.*,t2.url as image_url,t3.price as updatedPrice from catalogs 
        left join(select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product_id order by url desc ) as rowNo from media_link ) as t2 on (catalogs.id = t2.product_id and rowNo=1) 
         left join(select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product_id order by price desc ) as rowNo from assign_products  ) as t3 on (catalogs.id = t3.product_id )

Comment: I am new in MySQL and this is my query

Answer (score 2):

Left join and coalesce

```
select t1.pid,name, coalesce(t2.price,t1.price), weight
from t1
left join t2 on t1.pid = t2.pid;
```

Comment: let sql = SELECT count(*) as allProducts from catalogs + condition + `;select catalogs.*,t2.url as image_url,t3.price as updatedPrice from catalogs left join(select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product_id order by url desc ) as rowNo from media_link ) as t2 on (catalogs.id = t2.product_id and rowNo=1) left join(select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product_id order by price desc ) as rowNo from assign_products ) as t3 on (catalogs.id = t3.product_id )

Comment: That's a different question...if you want your code fixing delete this question add create a new one on that basis.